# Java.Lang.ClassCastException: 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ap cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup' Xamarin

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy recibiendo un error tras correr una clase para llamar al mapa de **Xamarin.Forms.Maps**

> Java.Lang.ClassCastException: 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ap cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup'

Justo cuando llamo a mi mapa con **CurrentLocation**

```
        public async Task CurrentLocation()
    {
        try
        {
            var pos = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();


            Mapx.MoveToRegion(
            MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
            new Position(pos.Latitude, pos.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1)));


            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(pos.Latitude, pos.Longitude),
                Label = "Mi ubicacion",
                Address = "  usted se encuentra aqui",

            };
            Mapx.Pins.Add(pin);


         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            DisplayAlert("Err", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok"); ;
        }

    }
```

Alguien sabe como puedo poner mi mapa, aquí les dejo mi `xmal`

```
  xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
```

```html
        <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Margin="20,40,20,20">

            <Button
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"    BackgroundColor="#DCF8C6"  TextColor="#225374"
            WidthRequest="200"
            Text="lavado al instante"
            Clicked="Lavadobtn_Clicked"
              />
            <Button
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   BackgroundColor="#DCF8C6"  TextColor="#225374"
            WidthRequest="200"
            Text="Registrar Auto"
            Clicked="AddCarbtn_Clicked"
            />
        <Button
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   
            Text="Direcciones"
              x:Name="Direccionbtn" 
                        Clicked="Direccionbtn_Clicked"
             BackgroundColor="#DCF8C6"  TextColor="#225374"
            WidthRequest="200"  Margin="0,0,0,30"
            />

            <maps:Map x:Name="Mapx" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"  />

        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView >
```

Comment: Me parece que no deberías tener problema actualmente con las versiones mayores a 3, que versión usas? agrega como estas agregando el mapa por favor, de cualquier forma agrego una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Como opción para solucionar el error:

> ClassCastException: 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ap cannot
>   be cast to android.view.ViewGroup'

Es eliminar el mapa usando el método [OnDisappearing()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.ondisappearing?view=xamarin-forms) y volver a agregarlo nuevamente en [OnAppearing()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms).

Puedes revisar este hilo relacionado

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81768/launching-a-modal-over-a-page-containing-a-map-maps-ad-m-cannot-be-cast-to-android-view-viewgroup

Ejemplo:

```
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {


           if (this.mapView.Parent == null) {
                try {

                    //* Reutiliza map
                    this.mapViewLayout.Children.Insert(0, this.mapView);

                } catch (NullReferenceException ex) {


                } catch (Java.Lang.ClassCastException ex) {

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }




        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {


             if (this.mapView.Parent != null) {
                try {
                    //*Elimina Mapa
                    this.mapViewLayout.Children.Remove(this.mapView);
                } catch (NullReferenceException ex) {

                } catch (Java.Lang.ClassCastException ex) {

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: podrias adjuntar el codigo de tu respuesta?

Comment: Agregue un ejemplo, saludos.

Comment: oye Java.Lang es un libreria?

Comment: No, `java.lang` es el [paquete básico](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) (core) del lenguaje Java, que contiene las clases básicas e imprescindibles